# How to deal with routes that don't respond to GET in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

I have a singleton route that looks like this:

```
resource :avatar, :only => [:edit, :update]
```

When a user edits the avatar, they go to /avatar/edit to view the form, when they save they are sent with a put request to /avatar and then redirected back to /avatar/edit. What should happen when we get a GET request to /avatar?

At the moment the route is not recognized and a generic 404 is returned. But this happens way more often than it should, so I feel we should do something about it. I'm tempted to add a:

```
get "/avatar" => redirection("/avatar/edit")
```

Any reason not to do that? any dangers in doing it?

I'm not sure I have all the reasons why this error happen, but I know some:

- There's an error so instead of redirecting, the user is just shown the edit form again in the put route, but then, instead of re-submitting, the user re-uses the url (pressing enter in the url field, copying and pasting, bookmarking, etc).
- The user at that point decides to change locale (happens often because the error message is the first time the person actually needs to understand the web site, so they decide to switch language to one that they understand) which of course generates a get in the same URL.

I now having a plain redirection wouldn't be the best in the second case, because the error is lost, but at least it's better than a 404.

Comment: you are not able to grep through the access logs to find out why people are getting that 404? i often see that bots are trying to hit those pages and instead render a moved-permanently for them, so that this page gets out of the index.

Comment: @phoet there are no pages that were moved here and I really don't care about finding out all the reasons why someone is getting a 404. There are no links to those pages, so people arriving at them will have done something out of the ordinary, thus, not providing a useful http referrer, so going through the logs won't shed much light in the matter of why they are arrived at that page.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the confusion with this route is that it is plural and yet refers to a singleton.  Any chance that you could use just "avatar"? If I went to a route "/avatars" I would expect a list of avatars.  If it is singular, then I would expect "/avatar" to view the avatar.  I also think this might be useful in a route like "/avatar.jpg" that would respond with the avatar image.  However, if your specs define no use for a show and always to edit try:

```
get "/avatars" => "avatars#edit"
```

or the singular

```
get "/avatar" => "avatars#edit"
```

Comment: I was using plurals because I remember reading in the Rails documentation that I shouldn't use singular. I think the problem would exist even with singulars as I don't have any show view. I updated the answer to remove that confusion (and I'm going to do the same with my code).

Comment: Any reason you are running the action and not redirecting?

Comment: @J.PabloFernández I am routing instead of redirecting because it saves a trip back to the client.  Now, this may have changed when redirect was introduced in the routes as opposed to in the controller, but I think that it functions the same.  Routing is better because we aren't changing any of the information.  However, the url will not be changed.

Comment: @J.PabloFernández I don't see any problem with redirection here.  In my opinion if you always want the edit and no show then the show route should go to the edit.  The fact that people are putting this into their browser shows that it is intuitive to write the show route.

Comment: I had this conversation before... about showing an edit form in the show action. It seems a lot of people believe it breaks the RESTful convention. I'm not sure. If you serve something more than HTML then it would be broken (html show is a different thing than json show). The reason why I pick a redirect instead of just serving the content is to avoid serving the same content under two different URLs.

Comment: I does break the RESTful convention, but for good reason–your specs require it.  I would definitely rather that a show route that just displays the avatar (or some other use depending on format) and then a link to edit it, but if that is not possible it is fine. It is okay to break convention when you recognize it is your intention.

Comment: @J.PabloFernández I looked up the docs for resource and the example there uses a singular `account`. http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html#M000308